# jQuery image transitions

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to grasp what I have to do here. I'm trying my hand at creating a simple image slideshow, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it work. It's not running through my for loop, and I can't see why. Here's a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/xnEGt/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/xnEGt/6/

What was wrong:

1. Images had first to be hidden via CSS, only first image visible
2. By using a for loop all the images will be shown only once. Note that the .delay() doesn't affect the loop so all the iterations will be made at once
3. You can solve this by using a recursive implementation using setTimeout
4. `.get(0)` and `.get(1)` selectors were also wrong, use `nth-child(i)` instead.

   ```
   var slideCount = $('.slider div.slide').length;
   nextPic(0);

   function nextPic(i){

       var next = (i+1)%(slideCount+1);

       $('.slider div:nth-child('+i+')').fadeOut(100);
       $('.slider div:nth-child('+next+')').fadeIn(100);  

       setTimeout(function(){nextPic(next);},1000);
   }
   ```

   Or a more compact implementation using `.get()` selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/xnEGt/7/

Comment: That works really well, I don't think I would have come up with that for a while. I was tinkering with recursion, but hadn't made much progress. One hiccup I've noticed though is that it runs through the first image twice. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, that's because nth-child starts counting from 1, whereas .get() is 0-based.